# How to use a custom change in node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, jar, migration, liquibase

I developed some classes that implement CustomTaskChange and built a jar file.
Then I loaded that jar in the liquibase classpath

```
const myConfig = {
  ...POSTGRESSQL_DEFAULT_CONFIG,
  changeLogFile: 'db/master/changelog.xml',
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/saft-demo-dump?allowMultiQueries=TRUE',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '*******',
  classpath:"jar/postgresql-42.2.20.jar;jar/migrations-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
}
const instTs = new LiquibaseTS(myConfig);
```

I am trying to access one class through an XML file but I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException`.How can I use it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
    <changeSet author="fabio" id="bd69067q-qr00-4400-902b-0091c5d29681">
        <customChange class="liquibase.change.custom.CustomChange.MultipleAdd"
                      suffix="transactions" columnName="NODE_COLUMN" columnType="varchar(250)">

        </customChange>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is probably because we have to use `:` in the classpath attribute as a separator, not a `;`.